# can't access form made in admin module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have made module Admin. In this module, in controller I have called form

```
class Admin_AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function indexAction()
{
    //$form = new Application_Form_Login();
    $form = new Admin_Form_Admin();
    $this->view->form = $form;     
}

}
```

But In controller its giving error -> Class 'Admin_Form_Admin' not found in application\modules\Admin\controllers\AdminController.php

My forms is in application\modules\Admin\forms\Admin.php.Below is my form code

```
class Admin_Form_Admin extends Zend_Form
{

public function init()
{

    this->setMethod('post');

    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */

    $user = $this ->CreateElement('text','username');

    $password = $this->createElement('text','password');

    $login = $this->createElement('submit','button');

    $this->addElements(array($user,
                              $password,
                              $login
                        ));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things are required here...

1. You need to bootstrap the [modules resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.modules)

   ```
   ; application.ini
   resources.modules[] =
   ```
2. You need to set the modules directory in your front controller

   ```
   ; application.ini
   resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
   ```
3. You need a bootstrap class in your admin module

   ```
   <?php
   // application/modules/Admin/Bootstrap.php
   class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
   ```

With these three things in place, your code should work as-is.